# How to form a sentence like this correctly?

Tags: sentence-structure

1. > You should tell us the things that you think **they** are negative.
2. > You should tell us the things that you think are negative.

I came up with this example sentence and I would like to form sentences like that but I'm not sure which one is correct and why. Would you tell me, please? What I mean is "When you see anything negative, you should tell us".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *they* is not required because *'that'* in your sentence talks about *them!*

In other words, here, the *things* are indicated by *that* and thus, you don't need to re-introduce *those things* in your sentence by putting *'they'.*

Here you go:

> You should tell us the things ***that*** you think are negative.